# how to Increase speed of build time ,in android studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Nothing to do just first you go and  update all the library in app and project level gradel library
and then go to in gradle.property
and paste it.

myMinSdkVersion=21

org.gradle.daemon=true

org.gradle.parallel=true

myTargetSdkVersion=32

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx8192M

android.enableJetifier = true

android.useAndroidX=true

kotlin.incremental=true

org.gradle.caching=true

org.gradle.configureondemand=true.

->jvmargs increase according to your ram size.

and this one code paste in gradle-applevel
in block
android {
}

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

and then sync it and restart your android studio you see a magic

Comment: Is this a question or are you trying to share some knowledge? While self-answered questions are encouraged, they should actually take the form of a question and a separate answer post (and both need to meet the quality guidelines of this site). See [ask].